# Render/export latex into non-paper-oriented formats

Tags: formatting, lyx, pdf

I use Latex very much and I generate many PDF files. I love the output quality. However I almost never print these PDF files, I always read them from the computer. Thus I find it nonsense to have the content of my document divided in "papers" with a fixed width and height, and page numbers, etc. These are features inherited from the "old paper" we humans have been using from 4000 years ago. It would be much better if I could export my Latex documents to something more oriented to be read in a computer, in a similar way to which a Wikipedia page is rendered in the browser.

For example Lyx is a good approach to what I am looking for. It renders the equations and images with no paper margins, it adjusts the text depending on the window width, etc. But it is oriented to editing, not reading. And does not display important things such as the index, the references to figures, etc.

I wonder if there is any "more modern" file format than PDF, that maintains the high quality and high portability of PDF files but that is not paper-oriented and can be rendered e.g. as a web page. I have been googling for such a format and ways of export Latex with not much success.

Comment: (La)TeX is unable to directly produce an output that automatically changes width depending on the available screen dimensions.  You want *ml and might want to look into either MathML or mathjax.

Comment: By changing the “paper” size, margins and colors, you can make a PDF document [more pleasant to read on screen](http://frougon.net/writings/maths_notes/notes-perso-sur-cours-Ramis-Deschamps-Odoux/notes-RDO-screen.pdf) (I hope)... It's an experiment and isn't perfect, of course. You can find all versions of the same document (print, screen and fullscreen-just-for-fun) [here](http://frougon.net/writings/maths_notes/notes-perso-sur-cours-Ramis-Deschamps-Odoux/).

Comment: There have been several attempts to move from stone tablet format to more flexible scrolls. Papyrus was one good move. More recently Pdf tried to enhance the idea of word processor reflow and HTML should have but as we see on many web pages that has not fully taken root except for those invasive adverts, that follow us. E-pub is the best of the latest breeds but still has issues Markdown is an infant that could potentially work the same way that Latex does in the background before it is frozen into PDF.